# Parse.com: cannot create more than 9 objects using cloud job

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud, jobs

I have Cloud Job code like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("createMySpecialObjects", function(request, status) {

    var MySpecialObject = Parse.Object.extend("MySpecialObject");

    var count = 20 // 20 is greater than 9!

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var myObject = new MySpecialObject();
        myObject.save();
    }

    status.success("Objects created successfully.");
});
```

And I have only 9 created objects as result.

I suppose it is connected with 30 API calls per second. But maybe somebody else knows better?

Comment: You should use `Parse.Object.saveAll`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code snippet below shows how to save multiple objects by using `Parse.Object.saveAll`.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("createMySpecialObjects", function(request, status) {

    var MySpecialObject = Parse.Object.extend("MySpecialObject");

    var count = 20 // 20 is greater than 9!

    var toSaves = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var myObject = new MySpecialObject();
        toSaves.push(myObject);
    }

    Parse.Object.saveAll(toSaves, {
        success: function(saveList) {
            status.success("Objects created successfully.");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            status.error("Unable to save objects.")
        }
    }
});
```